# Solve a simple gradient equation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vectors, vector-analysis

The equation is $$\nabla a=\vec{B},$$ $$a=?$$

Example 1: $\vec{B}=\mbox{const}$. Then $$a=\vec{B}\cdot \vec{x},$$ where $\vec{x}$ is the position vector. This is true since $\nabla(\vec{B}\cdot \vec{x})=\vec{B}$

Could you give other examples? Most interestingly, what happens when $\vec{B}$ is no longer constant? What does $a$ equal then?

Comment: In general $a$ is called scalar potential. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_potential. Note though in physics a minus sign is seen in the definition, usually the mathematics definition does not constrain the minus sign. Are you looking for a formula or something?

Comment: Example 1 shows one solution of the equation; it will be very interesting to see others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the curl of a gradient is zero, $\vec{B}$ has to satisfy $\nabla \times \vec{B} = 0$ for this equation to make sense (take the curl of both sides to see this). This condition is actually the key to finding the inverse.

Suppose we have a simply-connected open region $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ where $\nabla a = \vec{B}$. Define
$$ A(\gamma) = \int_{\gamma} \vec{B} \cdot d\vec{x}, $$
where $\gamma:[0,1] \to \Omega$ is a smooth curve joining the fixed point $\vec{x}_0 \in \Omega$ to $\vec{x}$. Now, we can show that $A$ in fact only depends on the endpoint: if $\gamma'$ is another smooth curve joining $\vec{x}_0$ to $\vec{x}$,
$$A(\gamma)-A(\gamma') = \int_{\Gamma} \vec{B} \cdot d\vec{x}, $$
where $\Gamma$ is a piecewise-smooth closed curve, which we assume does not intersect itself. Since $\Omega$ is simply-connected, $\Gamma$ bounds a two-dimensional surface, and so Stokes's Theorem implies that the right-hand side is zero because the curl of $\vec{B}$ is zero. Hence $A=A(\vec{x})$.

One can also show that $\nabla A = \vec{B}$:
$$ A(\vec{x}+\vec{h})-A(\vec{x})-\vec{h} \cdot \vec{B}(\vec{x}) = \int_{\vec{x}}^{\vec{x}+\vec{h}} (\vec{B}(\vec{x}')-\vec{B}(\vec{x})) \cdot d\vec{x}', $$
and since $\vec{B}$ is continuous (or it wouldn't be differentiable), the integral is $o(\lVert h \rVert)$, so $\nabla A =\vec{B}$.

Therefore $A$ is always a solution to the original equation.

(The same result holds in higher dimensions using the exterior derivative instead of curl, and the more general version of Stokes.)

Comment: Is $\Omega$ a set in $R^3$? Could you show the proof that $\nabla A=\vec{B}$, because it doesn't immediately follow that a gradient of the integral will equal $\vec{B}$...